# need help to set an argument

Tags: perl, scripting

I need help modifying this code to scan multi-able ranges. It is in perl, however I'm sure you can help me figure out how to get it to take a start and finish and scan through all of the IPs between these 2 point. Here is the code:

```
#!C:\Program Files\perl\bin\Perl.exe -w


 # ------------------------------------------------------------ #
 use Net::Ping;
 use LWP::UserAgent;

# ------------------------------------------------------------ #
# my $basenet = "192.168.240";                                 #
# my $start_host = 1;                                          #
# my $end_host = 25;                                           #
# ------------------------------------------------------------ #
$num_args = $#ARGV + 1;
if ($num_args != 3) {
  print "Usage: perl.pl [network-base] [start_ip] [end_ip]\n\n";
  print "Example: perl.pl 192.168.1 20 44\n";
  print "This will run the check on these IP's: 192.168.1.20-44.\n";
  exit -1;
}

my $basenet=$ARGV[0];
my $start_host=$ARGV[1];
my $end_host=$ARGV[2];
```

Im guessing it would need a 4th argument. like

my $extranet=$ARGV[3];

Please help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and use proper markup for code. See the [markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for details on how that works. Please mark code-blocks and inline code appropriately. It is very hard to read your question right now.

Comment: I've tried to format your question better myself, but I can't be sure of your meaning in several places. Please fix it.

Comment: can you define the meaning of  **multi-able ranges**. I  do not know the meaning.

Comment: you can generate those IPs using any loop and there is no need to forth argument. but what do you mean by scan and how the scan will work

Comment: i need this to ping 192.168.1.x through 192.168.5.x as it is.. it only pings 1 range that i define..the base, the starting  and end ip.

Comment: *"as it is.. it only pings 1 range that i define"* Your code does nothing but copy three arguments from `@ARGV`. Where is the rest of your program?

Comment: *"Im guessing it would need a 4th argument. like `my $extranet=$ARGV[3]`"* I think you have your answer there. Unless you show what the code already does and what you want it to do with `$extranet` there's nothing more to add.

Comment: If you want to ping everything between `192.168.1.0` and `92.168.5.255` then why don't you just pass those to addresses as parameters? I'm unclear what your fourth parameter is supposed to do.

Comment: Hello Borodin, can you show me a example?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Code

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;

 use Net::Ping;
 use LWP::UserAgent;
my $num_args = $#ARGV + 1;
if ($num_args != 5) {
  print "Usage: perl.pl [network-base] [start_ip] [end_ip] [range_start] [range_end]\n\n";
  print "Example: perl.pl 192.168 20 30 1 2\n";
  print "This will run the check on these IP's: 192.168.1.20- 192.168.2.30.\n";
  exit -1;
}

my $basenet=$ARGV[0];
my $start_host=$ARGV[1];
my $end_host=$ARGV[2];
my $range_start =$ARGV[3];
my $range_end = $ARGV[4];

for(my $j =$range_start; $j<= $range_end ;$j++ )
{
        for(my $i =$start_host; $i<= $end_host ;$i++)
        {
                my $new_ip = "$basenet.$j.$i";
                print "$new_ip\n";

                my $p = Net::Ping->new();
                if ($p->ping($new_ip)) {
                        print "$new_ip : active\n";
                }
                else{
                        print "$new_ip : inactive\n";
                }


        }
}
```

The above code will process your basenet , start_host and end_host data and generate a IP based on those iputs and then checks the IP is active or not .

output (running using :  `perl abc.pl  192.168 20 30 1 2` )

```
192.168.1.20 : inactive
192.168.1.21 : inactive
192.168.1.22 : inactive
192.168.1.23 : inactive
192.168.1.24 : inactive
192.168.1.25 : inactive
192.168.1.26 : inactive
192.168.1.27 : inactive
192.168.1.28 : inactive
192.168.1.29 : inactive
192.168.1.30 : inactive
192.168.2.20 : inactive
192.168.2.21 : inactive
192.168.2.22 : inactive
192.168.2.23 : inactive
192.168.2.24 : inactive
192.168.2.25 : inactive
192.168.2.26 : inactive
192.168.2.27 : inactive
192.168.2.28 : inactive
192.168.2.29 : inactive
192.168.2.30 : inactive
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks so much!!  this will work for 1 range.. can you help and make it for several ranges... for example  192.168.1.1-192.168.2.254?

thank you again!
perl.pl 192.168.1 1 254 2
this should check if ip's 1-254 are active and the last number is for the base going up. the base was 1 so 1+1=2.. please help with this. Thanks!

Comment: you can take total 5 arguments like `perl.pl 192.168. 1 254 1 2`  last two arguments for 3rd position of the IP. It will be much easier

Comment: can you show me a example of that? or how the syntax would be?

Comment: you can take another for loop for the range for example `for(my $j = $start_range ; $j <=$end_range; $j++)` to process your range part and create the new ip using `$i` and `$j`

Comment: can you modify the answer to include this change? i don't understand.

Comment: Hello Arjit, thanks so much, i need help using this code and putting it to this website to make it scan multible ranges http://fm4dd.com/security/check-console-defaults.htm
can you help me?skp i7monster  pleasee..

Comment: what kind of problem, you are facing  ? explain it properly.Otherwise its very difficult to help.

Comment: Hi Arjit, I believe i will make you the correct answer for your great work. But Please can you help me by going to this website. and tell me what to modify to make it scan mutible ranges.. like you have there..please! add me to skp